# How to test if a method returns an array of a class in Jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I'm going to test a method (using TypeScript language) to make sure it returns an array of a class.

Here is my code:

```
it('should return an array of Entity class', async () => {
    expect(await service.getAll()).toBeInstanceOf(Entity[]);
});
```

But it shows the following error message at `[]`:

> An element access expression should take an argument.

Comment: You can't pass a type as a value, they're erased in compilation.

Comment: So, how can I achieve my goal, making sure that the getAll method would return an array of Entity classes?

Comment: Is that a useful test? Do you not know what _values_ you should be getting? It's unclear what the actual context is.

Comment: TypeScript already did that for you before runtime. Just add the return type to the `getAll` function, like `getAll(): Promise<Entity[]>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Jest tests are **runtime** tests, they only have access to runtime information. You're trying to use a type, which is compile-time information. TypeScript should already be doing the type aspect of this for you. (More on that in a moment.)

The fact the tests only have access to runtime information has a couple of ramifications:

- **If** it's valid for `getAll` to return an empty array (because there aren't any entities to get), the test **cannot** tell you whether the array *would have* had `Entity` elements in it if it hadn't been empty. All it can tell you is it got an array.
- In the non-empty case, you have to check *every element* of the array to see if it's an `Entity`. You've said `Entity` is a class, not just a type, so that's possible. I'm not a user of Jest (I should be), but it doesn't seem to have a test specifically for this; it does have `toBeTruthy`, though, and we can use `every` to tell us if every element is an `Entity`:

  ```
  it('should return an array of Entity class', async () => {
       const all = await service.getAll()
       expect(all.every(e => e instanceof Entity)).toBeTruthy();
  });
  ```

  **Beware**, though, that all calls to `every` on an empty array return `true`, so again, that empty array issue raises its head.

If your Jest tests are written in TypeScript, you can improve on that by ensuring TypeScript tests the compile-time type of `getAll`'s return value:

```typescript
it('should return an array of Entity class', async () => {
    const all: Entity[] = await service.getAll()
    //       ^^^^^^^^^^
    expect(all.every(e => e instanceof Entity)).toBeTruthy();
});
```

TypeScript will complain about that assignment at compile time if it's not valid, and Jest will complain at runtime if it sees an array containing a non-`Entity` object.

---

But [jonrsharpe has a good point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71717652/how-to-test-if-a-mothod-returns-an-array-of-a-class-in-jest#comment126743868_71717652): This test may not be *useful* vs. testing for specific values that should be there.